# How to write Sql query for this scenario, for order, batch inventory management Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

Scenario: if order qty is less than or equal to first available batch quantity then display first batch, if order qty is greater than the qty of first available batch then display both batches for this product.

Tables looks like this

**Order** table

```
id | PId| Qty
```

**Batch** table

```
bid, pid, qtyinhand,expiry date
```

I have tried the following on

```
SELECT  
    pm.ProductID as [Product ID], pm.ProductCode as [Product Code],
    pm.BarCode, pm.ProductName as [Product Name], 
    m.Pack,  
    SUM(od.OrderQty) as [Order Qty],
    SUM(od.OrderQty) * m.Pack, 
    0 as DeliveryNoteQty, 
    SUM(od.ConvertedQty) as [Order Qty(Units)],   
    CONVERT(varchar(20), sm.ExpiryDate, 105) AS [Expiry Date], 
    sm.BatchID, sm.QuantityInHand as gcount 
FROM 
    OrderFormHeader oh 
INNER JOIN 
    OrderFormDetail od ON oh.OrderFormID = od.OrderFormID  
INNER JOIN 
    ProductMaster pm ON pm.ProductID = od.ProductID 
INNER JOIN 
    ProductMultipleUnits m ON pm.ProductID = m.ProductID 
                           AND od.UnitID = m.UnitID  
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP 1 
         sm1.QuantityInHand, sm1.BatchID, sm1.ExpiryDate 
     FROM 
         StockMaster sm1 
     WHERE 
         sm1.ProductID = pm.ProductID 
     ORDER BY 
         sm1.ExpiryDate ASC) sm  
WHERE 
    pm.ActiveFlag = 1 
    AND m.ActiveFlag = 1 
    AND oh.OrderFormID = 89 
GROUP BY 
    pm.BarCode, pm.ProductID, pm.ProductCode, pm.ProductName, m.UOI, 
    m.Pack, sm.QuantityInHand, sm.BatchID, sm.ExpiryDate 
ORDER BY
    pm.ProductCode, sm.ExpiryDate ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

With order and batch tables, you can write similar to one below

```
select 1 'id',1 'pid',100 'qty' into #order
insert into #order
select 2,2,50


select 1 'bid',1 'pid', 50 'qtyinhand', GETDATE() 'expirtydate' into #batch

insert into #batch
select 2,1,25, GETDATE()

insert into #batch
select 3,1,25, GETDATE()

insert into #batch
select 4,2,125, GETDATE()

insert into #batch
select 5,2,23, GETDATE()

insert into #batch
select 5,2,23, GETDATE()

go

with order_cte(pid,batchid)
as
(
    select pid,min(bid) from #batch
    group by pid
)

select ord.pid,bat.bid,bat.qtyinhand into #result from order_cte cte
inner join
#order ord on cte.pid = ord.pid
inner join
#batch bat on bat.bid = cte.batchid
where ord.qty <= bat.qtyinhand

insert into #result
select ord.pid,bat.bid,bat.qtyinhand from #order ord
inner join
#batch bat on ord.pid = bat.pid
where ord.pid not in (select pid from #result)


select * from #result
```